# Django + mod_wsgi: Why is empty url pattern always evaluated?

Tags: python, django, apache, url, mod-wsgi

I have a very simple Django project with an url-pattern, similar to this one:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^log/', include('apps.logging.urls')),
    url(r'^OPTION1/?', index, name="index"),
    url(r'^OPTION2/?', index, name="index"),
    url(r'^$', index, name="index"),
    url(r'^.+/?', RedirectView.as_view(url="/", permanent=False)),
)
```

So essentially, I want the index view to be rendered, when the url is either `/OPTION1`, `/OPTION2` or `/`. I also tried to put this logic into one single regular expression, but I always ended up with the same problem:

As soon as I'm working in production mode on an actual server, the emtpy url patter (`^$`), gets always evaluated in addition to the normal one. So if someone navigates to `/OPTION1`, the index view will actually called twice, once with `/` and once with `/OPTION1` as path.

As soon as I comment out the empty url patter everything works fine. I also have no redirects (except the one that you see in the url pattern, but I can comment it out and the problem persists), that could cause this problem and the status code returned is always 200.

So has someone any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't seeing a parallel request by the browser for /favicon.ico or something? Check your Apache access logs to make sure there isn't some parallel request.

Answer (score -1):

u can use this to redirect to ur home page upon xyz option:

```
url(r'^/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', anotherIndex),
```

and inside the view u can use this:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect

def anotherIndex(request, slug):
    redirect_url = "/"
    if slug == "OPTION1":
         redirect_url = "/OPTION1"
    elif slug == "OPTION2":
         redirect_url = "/OPTION1"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a redirect loop?

Comment: u r actually sending 4 urls over the same method Index, other then log and admin, u r sending all 4 urls to the same view, no matter what url u call, u will be redirected for the view Index

Comment: yes, that is supposed to work that way. But my question about your method was, if that wouldn't result in an infinite loop of redirects, since you are redirecting to the same url you came from.